# How can I Join Two Output Streams Into One Input Stream in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, redirect, io, scripting, piping

Specifically, I want to pass a date and a csv file into a python script. I understand how to pass in one of those using a `|`, but how can I pass both of them into the script and into separate variables?

Comment: If your python script accept arguments, that's all done.

Comment: @sodawillow your comment doesn't make sense

Comment: Does `Tee-Object` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx help?

Answer (score 0):

Development of my comment, after installing Python (3.5) and quickly writing my first Python script (*yay!*):

script.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

print(len(sys.argv), 'arguments:')
print(str(sys.argv))
```

PowerShell call (with script.py on my desktop):

```
& python "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\script.py" (Get-Date).ToString() "path/to/CSVFile.csv"
```

Output:

```
3 arguments:
['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\script.py', '24/06/2016 17:50:37', 'path/to/CSVFile.csv']
```

To me, this addresses *I want to pass a date and a csv file into a python script*.

*I'm pretty sure I missed the point :) ...*